# How can I send XML data format from browser to server using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

I would like to know if there is a way in jQuery to send data to server from a browser in XML format?

Thanks,
Sana.

Answer (score 2):

XML is just text so just send it as a string parameter in an AJAX request. Simple as that.